# Show that $\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\right)dx=2+\frac{\pi ^2}{2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Show that $$\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\right)dx=2+\frac{\pi ^2}{2}$$
It is clear the function gives infinity value when the $x=4$, so how can I find the above value?

Comment: You would have to do an improper integral, because it has an infinity in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $\frac{4u}{1+u}$, then $u$ with $v^2$, we are left to prove that:

$$ 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}\arctan\sqrt{u}}{(1+u)^2}\,du=8\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{v^2\arctan v}{(1+v^2)^2}=2+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\tag{1}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ 8\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\sin^2 t\,dt = 2+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\tag{2}$$
through $v=\tan t$. Now $(2)$ easily follows from integration by parts.

Comment: Not exactly "trivial;" you'd need to finish off with integration-by-parts, right?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: yes, exactly.